# How to create my own serializer from app engine types to Android over RPC

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to serialize the Text db type to something that Android can deserialize. Any pointers on the subject ?

Thanks,
Efi

Answer (score 0):

The Text type just stores a Unicode string - serializing it is just a matter of encoding it in a given codec (eg, UTF-8). If that's all you need to send, just send it in the plain in the body of the response.